# Custom rewrite slug break permalinks to taxonomy archive

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type named **datacenter_news** and a taxonomy for it named **dc_news_tax**. Both the post type archive and taxonomy archive works as it should. But when i try to add a custom rewrite slug named **datacenter-news** to the post type the URLs to my taxonomy terms stops working and give me the 404 page.

Right now the permalink structure looks like this.

```
datacenter_news/dc_news_tax/term
```

**and here is how i want it to look like**

```
datacenter-news/dc_news_tax/term
```

Here is the registered post type.

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_datacenter_news() {

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Data Center News", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Data Center News", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Data Center News", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => true,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "datacenter-news", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "news_tag", "dc_news_tax" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "datacenter_news", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_datacenter_news' );
```

and here is the registered taxonomy

```
function cptui_register_my_taxes_dc_news_tax() {

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "News Category", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "News Category", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "News Category", "custom-post-type-ui" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'dc_news_tax', 'with_front' => true,  'hierarchical' => true, ),
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "dc_news_tax",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Terms_Controller",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => false,
        );
    register_taxonomy( "dc_news_tax", array( "datacenter_news" ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_dc_news_tax' );
```

My permalink settings for the post type looks like this `/%dc_news_tax%/%postname%/`

What do i need to change to get custom rewrite slug to work with the URLs to my taxonomy terms?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this. I'd refer to the the documentation in regards to creating custom post types. First i'd try changing this in your code. Then refresh permalinks

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/complete-guide-custom-post-types/

From

```
register_post_type( "datacenter_news", $args );
```

To

```
register_post_type( "datacenter-news", $args );
```

From

```
register_taxonomy( "dc_news_tax", array( "datacenter_news" ), $args )
```

To

```
register_taxonomy( "dc_news_tax", array( "datacenter-news" ), $args )
```